# Can't catch ListView item MotionEvent action after updating ImageResource child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I got a custom ListView which I fill with an Adaptar. During my application the items within the list will change according to their status so I'm updating my ImageViews like so:

```
mStatusIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgStatusIcon);
mStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_cancel);
```

So far so good. The problem is that I want some kind of focus/hover state on a certain part of my layout. I've set up an `OnTouchListener()` on my `View mHitfield` in my layout xml.

I can catch all the relevant actions: `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL`.

The problem is that when I change my `ImageView mStatusIcon` the next action I catch is always `ACTION_CANCEL`.

```
View mHitfield = (View) findViewById(R.id.outerShape);

mHitfield.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {

        int currentAction = event.getAction();

        switch(currentAction)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                // if I comment out these lines I keep receiving all actions
                // if I don't, I only receive ACTION_DOWN followed by ACTION_CANCEL
                mStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_download_normal);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 

                // if I comment out these lines I keep receiving all actions
                // if I don't, I only receive ACTION_DOWN followed by ACTION_CANCEL
                mStatusIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_download_hover);
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening and if there is a way to work arround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not really sure why it happened but it was seems the TouchEvent was canceled because the layout was updated within the custom View  created. Once I didn't use a custom View but created a XML Layout instead the problem ceased to exist.